# Replace text entry for datetime to calendar date picker icon in Django form

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, forms

I've this template in my Django application for adding a training session:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>New session</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
    <p />
{% endblock content %}
```

The form contains a datetime field which appears as follows:

[image]

Is it possible to change this so instead of entering the datetime as text it can be selected from a calendar type icon? If so, how is this done?

This is my view:

```py
class SessionCreateView(CreateView):
    model = ClubSession
    template_name = 'session_new.html'
    fields = ['location', 'coach', 'date', 'details']
```

This is my model:

```py
class ClubSession(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    coach = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    details = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.location

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('session_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Comment: Please, post your form code

Comment: @DiegoMagalhães I added my view and model code. Is that what you're looking for? I don't have a forms.py.

Comment: Indeed, you don't need a form if you're using a CBV with fields defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With crispy forms, I think you will need a form for this.

```py
class ClubSessionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ClubSession
        fields = ['location', 'coach', 'date', 'details']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['date'].widget.attrs.update({'type': 'datetime-local'})

class SessionCreateView(CreateView):
    model = ClubSession
    form_class = ClubSessionForm
    template_name = 'session_new.html'
```

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances)

Keep in mind that not all browsers support `<input type="datetime-local">` - I believe only Chrome and Opera do. If you need it working in all browsers, you'll need a JS solution.

Comment: I can see that in Chrome if I remove `|crispy` from my template. I'd like this in all browsers though. Now that I've got that I should look for a JS solution to replace `<input type="datetime-local">`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, just search for a javascript datepicker and find one you like. I don't have any specific recommendations.

Comment: That's fine. Happy to look into that myself. Thanks for the help.